# Why can't I put an HSTS header on a meta tag?

Tags: html, http, firefox

So I'm using github pages and there's currently no way to force HTTPS with it, so I had the "bright" idea to put an HSTS header on a meta tag. So, I added this to the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Strict-Transport-Security" content="max-age=31536000" />
```

Aaand it didn't work. Why does it not work?! D:

My browser is Firefox Nightly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) User Agents are not to heed the HSTS attribute settings on  elements.

Comment: Uhh huh... it doesn't include a rationale? O_o

Comment: The goal of RFC 6797 is to provide specification of the HSTS protocol, not necessarily the discussion that led to its creation. The [Wikipedia article on HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#References) may direct you to the discussion on how the standard became the way it is.